# reduce a special 4D tensor to 3D tensor in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a 4D tensor **x** like:

```
(bs1, bs2, sent_len1, sentlen2)  # bs1 and bs2 are unknown and bs1 >= bs2.
```

and an indices tensor **ind** like:

```
(bs1, 1)
```

If I transform **ind** to a numpy array **np_ind** and do an operation:

```
cate_ind = to_categorical(np_ind, num_classes=None)
```

the shape of cate_ind is:

```
(bs1, bs2)
```

I want to use tensor **ind** to reduce the dimension of **x** from

```
(bs1, bs2, sent_len1, sentlen2) to (bs1, sent_len1, sentlen2)
```

the code example is:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers.merge import *


class CustomLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        super(CustomLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    # TODO:
    def dimension_reduction(self, tensor, indices):
        pass

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        tensor1, tensor2, ind = x[0], x[1], x[2]  # (bs1, sent_len1, wd) (bs2, sent_len2, wd) (bs1, 1)
        tensor2 = K.permute_dimensions(tensor2, [0, 2, 1])
        align = K.dot(tensor1, tensor2)
        align = K.permute_dimensions(align, [0, 2, 1, 3])  # (bs1, bs2, sent_len1, sent_len2)
        align = self.dimension_reduction(align, ind)  # (bs1, sen_len1, sent_len2)
        return align

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        t1_shape, t2_shape = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
        return t1_shape[0], t1_shape[1], t2_shape[1]


# model example
t1 = Input(shape=(7, 3))
t2 = Input(shape=(6, 3))
t3 = Input(shape=(1,))
output = CustomLayer()([t1, t2, t3])
model = Model([t1, t2, t3], output)

# data example
tensor1 = np.random.rand(10, 7, 3)  # (bs1, sent_len1, wd)
tensor2 = np.random.rand(4, 6, 3)  # (bs2, sent_len2, wd)
indices = np.array([0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1])  # (bs1, 1)
# indices = to_categorical(indices)  # (bs1, bs2)
print(model.predict([tensor1, tensor2, indices]))  # (bs1, sen_len1, sent_len2)
```

Comment: Which backend are you using? Tensorflow? And can you post relevant code where you create that Tensor?

Comment: the backend I'm using is tensorflow. I will upload an example later

Comment: I am not 100% sure how it works from Keras, but essentially you want to make use of [`tf.squeeze()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze), which you feed the tensor and the dimension you want to eliminate. I'll make a proper answer once you post the code and see that it works from Keras.

Comment: thank you for the advice, but squeeze only can reduce a dim with dim_len==1

Comment: Oh, my bad. So can you clarify on your example? Could the second value of `ind` something else like 1 in the second dimension? And which example (i.e. value for the second dimension) do you want to extract from `x` then? A random one?

Comment: the input tensor of t3 must be (1, ) we should transform t3 (or ind) to a specific shape which can help align reduce the dimension

Comment: @dennlinger, Hi, I have asked a new question which connect this one. would you please to have a look?